# Automatically fill div from file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am very new to html but need to throw together something for work as a POC, so apologies if I am asking a question that have been answered before, the truth is I wouldn't even know how to go about looking for the question because I am not sure how to ask it myself

I have included a description of what the code is doing at the moment and what I am trying to get it to do. I have also included the code itself which I have stripped it down to it's most simple form and embedded it as a snippet so that you can see how it behaves in it's current state.

CURRENT STATE

1. click on a topic
2. div opens up and hard coded, default information gets displayed
3. click on the topic name again/on the hide link/on any other topic, do any of these three things and the div closes again. If I click on any of the topics again, the same information get's displayed as before (regardless of what topic was selected)

WHAT I WOULD LIKE IT TO DO

1. click on a topic
2. takes the topic id and then reads data in from a text file relating to that specific topic (each topic has it's own file, it will read the entire file)
3. opens up the div as before except now it populates with the data that it just read in
4. if I hit the same topic again I want the div to close
5. if I hit close, obviously I want the div to close
6. if I hit another topic, instead of closing the div, I want it to just read in the info for that topic from it's own specific file and repopulate the div with the new data

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <title>HTML5 Skeleton</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">
      </script>
      <![endif]-->

    <style>

      body {
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; 
        font-size:0.8em;
      }
      header,nav,section,article,footer {
        border:1px solid grey; 
        margin:5px; 
        padding:8px;}
       nav ul {
        margin:0; 
        padding:0;
      }
       nav ul li {
        display:inline; 
        margin:5px;
      }
      .slidingDiv {
        height:300px;
        padding:20px;
        margin-top:10px;
      }

      .show_hide {
        display:none;
      }
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });

    });

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1 position="centre">Blah</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="show_hide">Topic 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="show_hide">Topic 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="show_hide">Topic 3</a></li>
      </ul>

    </nav>
    <section class="slidingDiv">
      <h1>Main heading</h1>

      <article>
        <h2>Sub heading</h2>
        <p>Blahblahblahblahblah</p>
      </article>
      <a href="#" class="show_hide">hide</a></div>
    </section>

    <footer>
     <p>Footer</p>
    </footer>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you like fries with that order ?

Comment: Read the docs on jQuery's [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), this should get you started.

Comment: if its not a lot of potential information to be fetched just output the data as a js object and reference that in your onclick evt. Be much faster than ajax calls. If its loads of information, use ajax.

Comment: @adenneo I don't think I get what you mean.

Comment: @Amadan Thanks! I will start reading it now :)

Comment: @David The data is just going to be statistics on customer environments, so mainly key performance indicators that will then be graphed or displayed somehow, so it cannot foresee it being a lot of data. I will try this and see how it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like using a database instead of a text file might be more along the lines of what you would need.  If you made a database that hosted the title, content, links, etc. related to each topic, you could fill each of the `<article>` tags from the database rows with a little bit of php.

Comment: This sounds like it would make a lot more sense than what I was thinking, I think I am going to go with this route.

Comment: @Ian if this is the route you go, make sure you mark it as the answer!

Comment: Will do, but the project hasn't been finished yet, kinda got put on hold until after xmas. I will report back :)